# The number of same elements in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

My aim is to display the number of identical elements in an array.

Here is my code:

```
a = [5, 2, 4, 1, 2]
b = []
for i in a
  unless b.include?(a[i])
    b << a[i]
    print i," appears ",a.count(i)," times\n"
  end
end
```

I get this output:

```
5 appears 1 times
2 appears 2 times
4 appears 1 times
```

The output misses `1`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:ruby-on-rails]. Your question also lacks a question. Please state what you want as the output, and how the output you are getting differs from it. Also, why are you "curious to solve it this way"? Would you be "curious to solve it this way" even if this way turns out to be completely wrong? (Not saying it's wrong yet, as I don't know what you're trying to do - but it certainly is unRubyish)

Comment: @Amadan edited the question. I'm new to ruby so just started off with a few basic programs. I know I'm close to my desired output here but just making a small mistake somewhere and wanted to find it.

Comment: I agree with Amadan. You say "solve it this way" but "this way" does not work. So now what? It's unclear at that point what sense your question can make. What constitutes a "this way" that also _does_ work? If it works, it isn't "this way" — unless you state more precisely what "this way" means. If "the aim of this program is to display how many times each element is repeated" then _any_ way that works should be acceptable.

Comment: What I'm trying to get to is - *what is* your desired output? `[nil, 4, 2]` does not look anything like "no of times an element is repeated in an array". What is `b` supposed to be? Also, it is probable that your error comes from misunderstanding what `i` is in `for i in a`, because you probably wouldn't write `a[i]` otherwise; but also `for ... in ...` is never ever used by Ruby programmers, and if you saw it in a book it's probably best to burn it.

Comment: `[nil,4,2]` was the o/p of `printb`  which i told was added for my reference anyway I have removed it as it is unnecessary here and what I get from your comment is using for loop is not a good practice in ruby? Just a beginner asking doubts @Amadan

Comment: Though it doesn't answer your question, the two most common ways of doing this are 1) use a *counting hash* (the second form of [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new)): `a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n,h| h[n]+=1 } #=> {5=>1, 2=>2, 4=>1, 1=>1}` or 2) use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by): `a.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:size) #=> {5=>1, 2=>2, 4=>1, 1=>1}`. The latter is the compact form of `a.group_by { |n| n }.transform_values { |v| v.size }`.

Comment: No worries, I answered in a bit more detail in an answer below. My main complaint was the fact that questions on StackOverflow need to be questions. Beginners' doubts are welcome - but knowing how to ask is crucial to getting a good answer. "You should use `each` instead of `for...in`" is a part of my trying to help you with your future in Ruby; "You should give as much information as possible in your question" is a part of my trying to help you with your future on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why or why were you in such a rush to select the first answer offered? Quick selections can discourage other answers and do not give those working on their answers enough time to finish before the checkmark has been awarded. There's no rush. Many here wait at least a couple of hours, some much longer. Incidentally, you can always withdraw the checkmark or change your selection if a better answer comes along.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a different way to do it, assuming I understand what "it" is (counting elements in an array):

```
a = [5,2,4,1,2]
counts = a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |element, counter|
  counter[element] += 1
end
# => {5=>1, 2=>2, 4=>1, 1=>1}
# i.e. one 5, two 2s, one 4, one 1.
counts.each do |element, count|
  puts "#{element} appears #{count} times"
end
# => 5 appears 1 times
# => 2 appears 2 times
# => 4 appears 1 times
# => 1 appears 1 times
```

`Hash.new(0)` initialises a hash with a default value `0`. We iterate on `a` (while passing the hash as an additional object), so `element` will be each element of `a` in order, and `counter` will be our hash. We will increment the value of the hash indexed by the element by one; on the first go for each element, there won't be anything there, but our default value saves our bacon (and 0 + 1 is 1). The next time we encounter an element, it will increment whatever value already is present in the hash under that index.

Having obtained a hash of elements and their counts, we can print them, of course, `puts` is same as `print` but automatically inserts a newline; and rather than using commas to print several things, it is much nicer to put the values directly into the printed string itself using the string interpolation syntax (`"...#{...}...")`.

The problems in your code are as follows:

- [logic] `for i in a` will give you elements of `a`, not indices. Thus, `a[i]` will give you `nil` for the first element, not `5`, since `a[5]` is outside the list. This is why `1` is missing from your output: `a[1]` (i.e. `2`) is already in `b` when you try to process it.
- [style] `for ... in ...` is almost never seen in Ruby code, with strong preference to `each` and other methods of `Enumerable` module
- [performance] `a.count(i)` inside a loop increases your algorithmic complexity: `count` itself has to see the whole array, and you need to iterate the array to see `i`, which will be exponentially slower with huge arrays. The method above only has one loop, as access to hashes is very fast, and thus grows more or less linearly with the size of the array.

The stylistic and performance problems are minor, of course; you won't see performance drop till you need to process really large arrays, and style errors won't make your code not work; however, if you're learning Ruby, you should aim to work with the language from the start, to get used to its idioms as you go along, as it will give you much stronger foundation than transplanting other languages' idioms onto it.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [5,2,4,1,2]
b = a.uniq

for i in b
  print i," appears ",a.count(i)," times\n"
end
print b
```

Result:

```
5 appears 1 times
2 appears 2 times
4 appears 1 times
1 appears 1 times
[5, 2, 4, 1]
```

Comment: This is very inefficient, as `a` is iterated once for each element of `b`. Other methods (see my comment on the question) conduct a single pass of `a`. Also `i` is a poor choice for the variable name as it normally is used to reference an index. I realize that the OP mistakenly thought it was an index, but that's no reason not to change it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Because he didn't put it in a context, I didn't care too much about OOP. I just wanted to correct his solution. In addition, for statement is just like a test to show the result.